# Is the HTML created by jQuery after the DOM is ready crawled by Google?

Tags: jquery, web-crawler

Is the HTML that is rendered in the jQuery `$(document).ready` crawled by Google?

Comment: FYI, JavaScript doesn't interact with the page via HTML. HTML is used to render a DOM *(Document Object Model)*, and JavaScript interacts with that DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Googlebot only downloads the page from the server. i.e. similar to doing a `wget` on the page url or like downloading a page using `curl`. It does not "execute" the scripts in the pages that it downloads. i.e. Googlebot is not a browser with a JS run-time etc.

That is, googlebot will only see the HTML that's sent as part of the page from the server. It does not see any HTML generated/rendered via `onready` on any other browser events.